# Targeting just the index.php header

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have code which applies a color to my navigation links. This header is on each page of my site. The text is inherently black with the 'white' class making it white. This is because it is removed as the page is scrolled down with code.

header.php

```
<body class="container">    

  <nav id="anim-nav" class="row white">

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'screen-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

 ...
```

css

```
.white { color: #fff;}
```

However, on the interior pages I don't want the white applied at all. I want the text to remain black. Not sure how to accomplish this as the header code is on all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code and it will display white only to home page and on other pages it will show black

```
body class="container">    

  <nav id="anim-nav" class="row <?php if(is_front_page() ){?>white<?php }?>">

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'screen-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
<style>
.white { color: #fff;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```